# How do you add a repeated field using Google's Protocol Buffer in C++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have the below protocol buffer. Note that StockStatic is a repeated field.

```
message ServiceResponse
{
    enum Type
    {
        REQUEST_FAILED = 1;
        STOCK_STATIC_SNAPSHOT = 2;
    }

    message StockStaticSnapshot
    {
        repeated StockStatic stock_static = 1;
    }
    required Type type = 1;
    optional StockStaticSnapshot stock_static_snapshot = 2;
}

message StockStatic
{
    optional string sector      = 1;
    optional string subsector   = 2;
}
```

I am filling out the StockStatic fields while iterating through a vector.

```
ServiceResponse.set_type(ServiceResponse_Type_STOCK_STATIC_SNAPSHOT);

ServiceResponse_StockStaticSnapshot stockStaticSnapshot;

for (vector<stockStaticInfo>::iterator it = m_staticStocks.begin(); it!= m_staticStocks.end(); ++it)
{
    StockStatic* pStockStaticEntity = stockStaticSnapshot.add_stock_static();

    SetStockStaticProtoFields(*it, pStockStaticEntity); // sets sector and subsector field to pStockStaticEntity by reading the fields using (*it)
}
```

But the above code is right only if StockStatic was an optional field and not a repeated field. My questions is what line of code am i missing to make it a repeated field?

Comment: Just curious, what exactly is the problem you are facing when you make it repeated?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No, you're doing the right thing.

Here's a snippet of my protocol buffer (details omitted for brevity):

```
message DemandSummary
{
    required uint32 solutionIndex     = 1;
    required uint32 demandID          = 2;
}
message ComputeResponse
{
    repeated DemandSummary solutionInfo  = 3;
}
```

...and the C++ to fill up ComputeResponse::solutionInfo:

```
ComputeResponse response;

for ( int i = 0; i < demList.size(); ++i ) {

    DemandSummary* summary = response.add_solutioninfo();
    summary->set_solutionindex(solutionID);
    summary->set_demandid(demList[i].toUInt());
}
```

`response.solutionInfo` now contains `demList.size()` elements.

Comment: Thank you.. I just realized the call to response->add_solutioninfo() ---- adds more than 1 element.. thank you!

Comment: `DemandSummary* summary = response->add_solutioninfo();` should be changed to `DemandSummary* summary = response.add_solutioninfo();` For some reason stackoverflow says the suggested edit queue is full

Answer (score 0):

Here the c++ sample code but may not efficient:

```proto
message MyArray
{
    repeated uint64 my_data = 1;
}
```

```cpp
//Copy
std::array<unsigned long long, 5> test={1,1,2,3,5};
mynamespace::MyArray pbvar;
auto *dst_ptr = keys.my_data();
google::protobuf::RepeatedField<google::protobuf::uint64> field{test.begin(), test.end()};
dst_ptr->CopyFrom(field);

//Output
for (auto it : pbvar.my_data())
    std::cout<<it<<" ";
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

Comment: this would be even more helpful if `keys == pbvar`

Comment: There supposed to be  `mutable_my_data`, the `my_data` getter is a const-cv-qualified one

Answer (score -2):

Another way of accomplishing the same thing:

```
message SearchResponse {
  message Result {
  required string url = 1;
  optional string title = 2;
  repeated string snippets = 3;
  }  
  repeated Result result = 1;
}
```

Comment: for **repeated string snippet** what will be the cpp code?